# Install wordpress alongside in laravel in apache server

Tags: wordpress, apache, laravel, .htaccess

I have put my wordpress in public/blog folder in laravel. In my case after putting this `RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)` into .htaccess file I can install and access wordpress through `www.mysite.com/blog`. The only problem is when I change permalinks from this `/blog/?p=123` to this `/blog/%postname%/`. It gives me error in laravel

`NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161`

so how can I have post with nice path like `www.mysite.com/blog/my-post`?

Comment: It'd be better to use a subdomain for that.

Comment: but I don't want to use sub domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just setting `RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)` is not enough.

Replace the line with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/`, so it'll ignore **all** URIs that start with /blog/.

Then don't forget to change the WP .htaccess too:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/   #change here
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L] #change here
</IfModule>
```